# Step-by-step to baking a model for export, so that it looks smooth but doesn't have all the faces of a subdivided mesh

Tags: modeling, vertices, normals

What's even the point of baking? I want to learn it because I've been told it can help me with my issue. I want to make my mesh appear subdivided, but that would bring it over 100,000 faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baking can be used to create the image texture for example a character. It can also be used to create normal maps. The below video teaches how to remove faces from a high poly mesh but still keep the detail in it by simply adding a normal.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApzVWuPa4A4